# Want to add a customize progress steps in Gravity form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Can someone explain to me what code is needed for modifying a Gravity Forms progress bar? I'd like to change the default progress bar to use custom graphics for each step.

[I want to show step bar like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjuxB.png) 
I tried following this gravity forms page but the directions that they have given on https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_progress_steps/#source-code   and it didn't work

Code:

```
add_filter( 'gform_progress_steps', 'progress_steps_markup', 10, 3 );
function progress_steps_markup( $progress_steps, $form, $page ) {
    $active_class = 'gf_step_active';
    $progress_steps = str_replace( $active_class, $active_class . ' your_custom_class', $progress_steps );
 
    return $progress_steps;
}
```